# Тире или запятая?1

Tags: пунктуация

Уместен ли в этих предложениях такой знак препинания?

1)**Если отпустят (-) пойду**.

2)**Когда будут деньги (-) я скажу**.

Answer (score 3):

(1)Если отпустят – пойду. **Постановка тире рекомендуется по грамматическим показателям:** пропуск второй части двойного союза, неполное главное предложение, разная структура главной и придаточной части.  Тире соответствует **паузе** в устной речи.

2)Когда **бУдут** деньги – я скажу. **Факультативное тире** при наличие авторской паузы, **логическое ударение** на "будут".

Сравнить: Когда будут деньги, я скажу. При отсутствии паузы ставится запятая, **стандартная** расстановка тонических ударений в конце каждой фразы.

Comment: >> *Если отпустят – пойду. Обязательная постановка тире* Не понимаю, зачем вводить в заблуждение? Что, запятая здесь ошибочна? Да ни в коем случае, она здесь предпочтительней тире.

Comment: Тире в СПП является неосновным знаком, но все случаи его употребления можно разделить на две группы: 1) для постановки тире есть грамматические показатели (наличие слов ЭТО,ТАК, неполное предложение, пропущенная часть союза, два придаточных и т.д. 2) грамматических показателей нет, но автор меняет стандартную расстановку ударений, логически выделяет определенное слово, вследствие чего делается пауза, которая обозначается тире.  Вы ведь тоже обратили внимание на разную структуру предложений, и решение у Вас тоже разное.

Comment: Но в первом предложении тире отнюдь не "обязательно".

Comment: Сравните: Если отпустят, охотно поеду. - Если отпустят - поеду. Эти предложения явно имеют разную структуру и интонацию. Но если вам не нравится слово "обязательно",  можно заменить "настоятельно рекомендуется". Если и это не подходит, то остановимся на  "мягкой" формулировке Розенталя - "постановке тире способствуют...".  А я (под  Вашим давлением) немного скорректирую ответ.

Comment: Структура – одинакова! Слово "охотно" меняет структуру?! А интонация... Почти любую фразу можно произнести с почти любой интонацией, поэтому пунктуация от интонации практически не зависит. От синтаксиса она зависит, то бишь от структуры.

Comment: Мне кажется, что для вас нет разницы между структурой предложения и его грамматикой, но  это разные вещи. Структура - это и количество слов в каждой фразе (структурном отрезке предложения), и их взаимное расположение. Обычно мы строим структуру нашей речи на интуитивном уровне, в частности меняя порядок и количество слов. Впрочем, это ОСОБАЯ ТЕМА, вряд ли мы  придем к взаимопониманию, обсуждая этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Тире в ваших примерах ставится.

В сложноподчиненном предложении может ставиться тире:

1) после придаточной части, стоящей перед главной частью (особенно при наличии слов это, вот, то в главной части):

Ср.:**Когда тоска — хорошо писать (Пауст.); Что в воздухе хлябь — на то уже не обращалось внимания (Ч.); Когда это кричит орел, сокол, ястреб, наконец, — это и красиво и мощно (М. Г.);**

См: [Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134)

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли, разве что как авторский знак. Нет причин для постановки. А во второй фразе уж совсем необоснованно.

"Паузы", на которые любит напирать Sibylla, совершенно не причина для постановки знаков препинания.